# How to have better understanding of Firebase Android Documentation?

Tags: firebase

I have done java for 6 months but when i try to go through the firebase android documentation on my own I don't understand it .I cant use the documentation on my own. please tell me what I should do  to properly understand it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is one of the most clear ones i ever seen, it is detailed and organized, but you can also check the [codeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/)

Comment: Should I do a lot of practice in object oriented programming?